# Remove Content after <!--more-> tags

Tags: posts, themes, read-more

Here with the structure of content in text editor

```
Content Before

<!--more->

Content After
```

I wanted to remove the "Content Before" in my single post

so instead I have this

```
Content Before
Content After
```

I will have the "Content After" on my single post only

```
Content After
```

How can I achieve this display?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set the `$stripteaser` parameter to `true`;

```
the_content('readmore', true);
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content

Comment: wow this so simple nice :)